# XmlTextReader I couldn't getting my data

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I couldn't get the value of a column.

I wrote  this code:

```
    XmlTextReader myReader = new XmlTextReader("./Redirect.xml");
    myReader.Read();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        if (myReader.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Element&&myReader.Name=="FL")
        {
            myReader.MoveToAttribute("val");
            if (myReader.Value == "POTENTIALID")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myReader.Value);
        }
    }
```

PRINT:

POTENTIALID

POTENTIALID

POTENTIALID

POTENTIALID

POTENTIALID

...

Can you help me I need to get all potentialIDs?How can I get 1786565000003649065(POTENTIALIDs)

[My XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX59Q.jpg)

```
 <Potentials>
     <row no="2">
        <FL val="POTENTIALID">1786565000003649065</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">1786565000000093009</FL>
        <FL val="Potential Owner"><![CDATA[Deneme]]></FL>
        <FL val="Amount"><![CDATA[3168]]></FL>
        <FL val="Potential Name"><![CDATA[G PLUS 183 KİRALIK]]></FL>
        <FL val="Closing Date"><![CDATA[2017-08-31]]></FL>
        <FL val="Stage"><![CDATA[Pazarlama Aşaması]]></FL>

     </row>
  </Potentials>
```

Comment: Show a relevant excerpt from your XML.

Comment: Sorry, I added now.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlTextReader myReader = new XmlTextReader("./Redirect.xml");   
while (myReader.Read())
{
    if (myReader.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Element&&myReader.Name=="FL")                
    {
        if (myReader.GetAttribute("val") == "POTENTIALID")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myReader.ReadString());
        }                    
    }
 }
```